# Colon after selector in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors

When I have this css:

```
.bigpoint {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

my div with class bigpoint has font size 40 pixels, as expected.

When I add a colon after the selector:

```
.bigpoint: {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

the styling is ignored.  I can't find any documentation about it, and linters seem to accept it both ways.  What's going on?

Rick

P.S.  My doctype is just `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: My guess is that it's thinking bigpoint is a property. It's just not how CSS syntax works. It's like asking why a dollar sign doesn't work in a random place in HTML.

Comment: First of all this is not applied only for chrome, is for all browsers. Second, I don't know why you need an empty `:` after the selector name

Comment: `csslint` seems to accept this, which can only be considered a bug. Pretty bad one at that.

Comment: Have reported a csslint issue at https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/issues/639.

Comment: The W3C CSS validator (http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) reports this as an error (`Parse Error [:]`).

Comment: This has now been fixed in csslint. See https://github.com/CSSLint/parser-lib/pull/206.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It thinks you are going to append a pseudo class to the selector.

```
.bigpoint:hover {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

But, CSS is extremely primitive in that it won't tell you it's wrong, it just won't work.

Answer (score 3):

The colon is a special symbol in CSS that delimits a [pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-classes). A valid selector cannot end with a trailing colon (unless it is escaped). If a colon is present, the character sequence that follows it must be the name of a known pseudo-class (or pseudo-element).

Why a linter would accept this syntax is beyond me. It is clearly invalid CSS.

Comment: Linters aren't aware of what pseudo-(element/class) are valid, they just check the syntax

Comment: @Joseph Young: Except there is no pseudo-class here. A pseudo-class consists of a colon followed by an ident. All there is here is a trailing colon, which is invalid CSS.

Comment: @IsraGab: It is, and that is why the selector `.bigpoint:` is invalid - the parser is expecting an identifier after the colon which isn't there.

Comment: I suppose it boils down to whether they check for that. I actually just found one which does say null element/classes aren't allowed. http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/csscheck/

Comment: @Joseph Young: That's a validator, not a linter, though I'd still expect a linter to perform some sort of validation unless it explicitly assumes the input is valid CSS.

Comment: I guess I can only accept one answer.  I accepted the most pithy one, but they were both helpful.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2171796: Brevity is not my strong suit :)